# Rate Of Change & First Derivative

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I have some data in Seconds (X axis) and % (y axis). Lets say for ten seconds the data below:

S = 0 % = 0.1

S = 1 % = 0.2

S = 2 % = 0.3

S = 3 % = 0.4

S = 4 % = 0.5

S = 5 % = 0.6

S = 6 % = 0.7

S = 7 % = 0.8

S = 8 % = 0.9

S = 9 % = 1.0

S = 10 % = 1.1

I know i can calculate the rate of change, lets say between 0 and 1 seconds with: ((0.2 - 0.1 )/0.1)*100 which would give ROC of 100%

So the maximum rate of change in these 10 seconds is actually 100%. So for my first question, if i wanted the max rate of change for 3 minutes from this data (180 seconds) would i use something like:

100% / 10 = 10% (per second average)

10% * 180 = 1800% (per 180 seconds)

1800 / 60 = 30 average per min

30 * 3 = 90% average ROC per min over 3 minutes

Is that correct?

My second question: After plotting the Second and Percent onto a graph, how would i work out what the First Derivative plot points would be? I am a bit lost with this part as i can't seem to get the first derivative calculation right.

I think im confused by the formula: f(x) - f(a) / x - a

because this function (f(x)) is not telling me what the function is to do with x. For example :

f(x) = x + 1

tells me that the output  = input + 1  , so what would be the output of f(x) ??

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ are your seconds, and $f(x)$ are the % on your y-axis. I don't see how the rate of change is 100%, as the value on the y-axis changes by 100% from $S=0$ to $S=1$, then by 50% from $S=1$ to $S=2$, then by 33.333..%, etc. The rate of change is constant, and is the value

$\displaystyle \frac{f(0+1) - f(0)}{(0+1) - 0} = 0.2 - 0.1 = 0.1$

for $S=0$, then it is

$\displaystyle \frac{f(1+1) - f(1)}{(1+1) - 1} = 0.3 - 0.2 = 0.1$

for $S=1$, etc.

This value is your first derivative as well, as the function is linear (given the discrete points you have listed). If you don't get this I suggest picking up a book on calculus. There are many good ones out there which will give you a good introduction to the derivative within the first chapter

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. When i say the rate of change was 100% i mean out of all the seconds checked the maximum rate of change i found was 100% , where as like you said others were 50% then 33.3333%  so the maximum rate of change in there was 100% ...or am i missing something?

I still don't follow the f(x) part, in your example you have f(0+1)  - f(0) ... where are the 0+1 and 0 coming from?

Comment: and i don't see what the f() is for here? I am actually a programmer so i understand what a function does, but in this case its not explaining what the expected output of f() should be? There is nothing in the function telling me what to do with x ??

Comment: A function in programming is not a mathematical function, unless you are doing functional programming. $f$ is a map from seconds $S$ to percent %. It maps $0$ to $0.1$, i.e. $f(0) = 0.1$. It maps $1$ to $0.2$, i.e. $f(1) =0.2$, etc.

Comment: And the derivative is calculated as $(f(x+h) -f(x))/(x+h - x)$, i.e. $\text{d}y/\text{d}x$ (the difference in $y$ divided by the difference in $x$)